# Creating various mini ToC fails to print desired ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I will be referring to the mwe below:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{s o m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\oldsubsection*{#3}%
     \addcontentsline{ptc}{subsection}{#3}}
    {\IfValueTF{#2}
       {\oldsubsection[#2]{#3}}
       {\oldsubsection{#3}}}
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Content only from section}
The ToC below should not contain the subsection* title class rather the sections only.
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{} % allows printing of subsection only
\section{A test section}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section*{Content from subsection*}
\startcontents[sections]
\printcontents[sections]{}{2}{} % allows printing of subsection only

\clearpage

\section{Test section in ToC}\lipsum[1]
\subsection*{Test subsection now in ToC}\lipsum[2]
\subsection*{Test subsection in ToC}\lipsum[3]
\stopcontents[chapters]
\end{document}
```

This question is more than likely related to the previous ones I have made earlier. Here is what I wish to achieve:

```
Chapter 1
mini ToC with sections only
Section 1
mini ToC with subsections* only
```

Seemingly, using `\stopcontents[mytoc]` and `\stopcontents[mytocc]` can possibly help but picture the document I am working on is one that has many chapters and many sections with many subsections*.

How can achieve the desired result?

Comment: `\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{} % allows printing of subsection only` what do you exactly show here? only sections? sections and subsections?

Answer (score 1):

This command will be usefule:

```
\newcommand{\nocontentsline}[3]{}
\newcommand{\tocless}[2]{\bgroup\let\addcontentsline=\nocontentsline#1{#2}\egroup}
```

You can use this to eliminate a section or subsection or ... from content list as follow:

```
\tocless\section{a section}
```

where the section is disappear on content list.

Comment: It does eliminate the subsection* from the section ToC under the chapter but it also eliminates from the subsection* ToC under each section.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. We use

```
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
```

for chapter minitoc to show only sections and

```
\printcontents[sections]{}{2}{
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\section*{Content from subsection*}}
```

for section minitoc to show only subsections

Note that i use here `\section*{Content from subsection*}` inside `\printcontents` i think it's better like this.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{s o m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\oldsubsection*{#3}%
     \addcontentsline{ptc}{subsection}{#3}}
    {\IfValueTF{#2}
       {\oldsubsection[#2]{#3}}
       {\oldsubsection{#3}}}
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Content only from section}
The ToC below should not contain the subsection* title class rather the sections only.
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}} 
\section{A test section}
\lipsum[1-2]
\startcontents[sections]
\printcontents[sections]{}{2}{
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\section*{Content from subsection*}} % allows printing of subsection only

\clearpage

\section{Test section in ToC}\lipsum[1]
\subsection*{Test subsection now in ToC}\lipsum[2]
\subsection*{Test subsection in ToC}\lipsum[3]
\stopcontents[chapters]
\end{document}
```